# How to use awk instead of cmp to store comparison results to variables

Tags: bash, awk

Assume I have a file called checkDuplicateDownload.sh to check the downloaded file for duplicate or not, by comparing the new one and the old one.

This is what I have done.

```
duplicate=`cmp $prevFile newFile -b`
```

Where `duplicate` is the variable to store the result from `cmp`, `prevFile` is the previous file, and `newFile` is the new file. If the files are the same, then `duplicate` has the value 0 else 1.

How to do the same as the `cmp` command above, but use awk and store the comparison result to a `duplicate` variable?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the dollar sign? Due to it, your `cmp` will end up with an error message. When you remove the dollar, it will work, but `duplicate` will not have a value of 0 or 1. In case the files differ, the value will be a longer string like "prevfile newfile differ: byte 10, line 1". In case they don't, the value will be the empty string. `awk` is not the right tool for comparing files. For one thing, `awk` was not made to work with binary files, and even when comparing text files, it would be overly complicated.

Comment: With `bash`, `md5sum` and `cut`: `if [[ "$(md5sum prevFile | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" == "$(md5sum newFile | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" ]]; then echo okay; else echo "not okay"; fi`

Comment: @Cyrus that seems an awfully complicated way to say `if cmp -s prevFile newFile; then … else … fi`

Comment: Options go before filenames, so the -b is misplaced (as well as adding nothing to the result). What comes out of the test is the stdout, not the exit result of cmp. Also the result is 1 if the files differ, so `duplicate` is exactly the wrong name. Discard the text output. Try `cmp -s old new; differ=$?`. Apart from `awk` being somewhat unsuitable, `cmp` exits as soon as it finds a difference, so can be more efficient.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant options don't necessarily go before filenames. Things like `ls file -al` will work as expected. Some people even put the filename first and write things like `<file wc -l`, but putting an option after an argument is absolutely supported. That's precisely why there is a need for the `--` notation to signify the end of options.

Comment: @terdon The `man` pages for `ls` and `cmp` say options come before any operands, and so does POSIX (and getopt(1) with POSIXLY_CORRECT). "Put the filename first" is a red herring -- that's a shell redirection, not a command argument. The purpose of `--` is to ensure operands are treated as intended even if they look like options, not vice versa. But mainly, this is an alien convention and probably not portable, and I prefer to discourage it.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yes, fair point about the `<`, that isn't really relevant. But the options after arguments is something that although I personally don't use as I find it confusing and unclear, certainly seems to be relatively common. My point was just that since options after operands is commonly supported, we can't really say that the `-b` is _misplaced_ in `cmp prevFile newFile -b`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that what you're describing is a silent comparison of two files. This first snippet will put the exit status from `cmp` into the variable `duplicate` (0=match, otherwise there was an issue; see `man cmp` for details of the exit status values)

```
cmp -s prevFile newFile
duplicate=$?
```

But I suspect what you are then going to do is to test the value of `$duplicate` and perform an action on it. In this case you might as well just test the exit value of `cmp` directly

```
if cmp -s prevFile newFile
then
    echo "Files match"
else
    echo "Files do not match (or one is missing, unreadable, etc.)"
fi
```

If you were intending to use variables, don't forget to double-quote them when you use them, i.e.

```
cmp -s "$prevFile" "$newFile"
```

And also consider whether it's possible that `$prevFile` might not yet exist

Finally, what about `awk`? It's not the right tool for this job, so don't use it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` for this. It just doesn't make much sense to do so. There are tools explicitly designed for file comparison (`diff`, `cmp`, `md5sum` etc.). On the other hand, `awk` is a powerful scripting language that can be used for arbitrary tasks. As such, you can indeed reimplement the existing functionality of these tools in `awk`, but you will gain nothing from that other than a slower, less efficient way of doing what these other tools do better.

For instance, this `awk` program will tell you if two files are identical or differ:

```
$ cat comp.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
  differ=0
}
NR==FNR{
  a[FNR]=$0; 
  last=FNR; 
  next
}
{ 
  if(FNR>last || "x"$0"x" != "x"a[FNR]"x" ){
    differ=1
    exit;
  }
} 
END{
  if(FNR<last){
    differ=1
  }
  print differ
}
```

So you could use that to store the comparison in a variable:

```
duplicate=$(comp.awk prevFile newFile)
```

The variable will be `0` if the files are the same and `1` if they are different. But you can do the same using existing tools faster, more efficiently and likely more reliably:

```
duplicate=$(diff -q prevFile newFile)
```

Granted, the value won't be a simple `1` or `0`, it will be either `Files prevFile and newFile differ` or an empty string but it makes no practical difference. Presumably, you would want to use the variable in a subsequent test operation, and you can do that perfectly well:

```
$ [[ -z $duplicate ]] && echo differ || echo same
differ
```

So there just seems to be no point at all in reinventing a slower, more error prone and cumbersome version of something that already exists.